# bootstrap column sizing not working on localhost 8000

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, localhost

I am currently trying to make bootstrap work on my localhost:8000. I have been working directly out of the index.html file by drag and dropping it to chrome.  Everything works correctly that way, however when I open up localhost in the command line using "$ php -S localhost:8000" the page loads but the bootstrap column sizes are no longer working correctly. I am not sure if I am using localhost wrong or if it is a bootstrap problem as I am new to both.  My header contains the following...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Domine:400,700|Montserrat+Alternates:400,700|PT+Sans+Caption' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsivemobilemenu.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

with my script tags at the end.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsivemobilemenu.js">    </script>
```

HTML code ...

```
<div class="row" id="results-section">
        <h1>Results</h1>
        <p><q>Soufflé jelly beans caramels tart wafer. Cheesecake icing lemon drops dragée. Liquorice marzipan jujubes dessert sweet pudding. Carrot cake muffin chocolate bar toffee topping I love I love dragée.</q> - annonymous</p>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 result">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/440/300/people/sepia">
            <h3>Paragraph Heading 1</h3>
            <p>I love chocolate bar fruitcake macaroon pie gingerbread cake. Pie dragée I love macaroon. Jujubes halvah apple pie. Ice cream cake brownie fruitcake danish pudding.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 result">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/440/300/tech/sepia">
            <h3>Paragraph Heading 2</h3>
            <p>Croissant I love powder wafer. Carrot cake halvah pie pastry I love donut I love gummies pastry. Sweet roll cake soufflé tiramisu. Jujubes caramels candy canes carrot cake apple pie danish halvah gummi bears dragée.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 result">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/440/300/animals/sepia">
            <h3>Paragraph Heading 3</h3>
            <p>Marzipan sugar plum gingerbread apple pie ice cream tiramisu tart. Chocolate liquorice pudding I love jelly-o. Biscuit lollipop candy canes marshmallow danish chocolate cake gummi bears macaroon cotton candy.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 result">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/440/300/arc/sepia">
            <h3>Paragraph Heading 4</h3>
            <p>Fruitcake liquorice cake. Candy brownie bonbon macaroon. Lollipop oat cake icing halvah danish. Cheesecake pie chupa chups gummies biscuit dessert.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 result">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/440/300/nature/sepia">
            <h3>Paragraph Heading 5</h3>
            <p>Liquorice danish donut I love jujubes cupcake. Apple pie bonbon chocolate bar dessert ice cream icing. Carrot cake chupa chups croissant.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 result">
            <img src="http://placeimg.com/440/300/tech/sepia">
            <h3>Paragraph Heading 6</h3>
            <p>Chocolate chocolate bar muffin jelly-o. Tart jelly beans I love sweet. Pudding toffee pastry donut. I love pudding gummies tiramisu.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any errors on the dev tools console?

Comment: Also, please show your HTML code with columns.

Comment: No error codes in console that are anything related. HTML code...added to question

Comment: *Is bootstrap loaded* (there should be a 404 error in the dev tools if not)? *Is the `.row` inside a `.container`* (or is html you pasted everything you have)? *What happens if you replace `css/bootstrap.css` with `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css`* (using a cdn instead of your local copies)?

Comment: Sorry I think I explained this wrong. The bootstrap is working but the breakpoints for the different screen sizes are at larger sizes in localhost.  The regular break points for col-sm-6 col-md-4 are 991px and 768px.  In my localhost the breakpoints change to 1240px and 960px, which i dont want.

Comment: You shouldn't have any content between `row` and `col-` elements. Put it all inside the `col-`